# Symlink two real directories with files in both

Tags: linux, filesystems, symbolic-link

I have two directories, with files in both of them:

```
./read/pub/
        |- file1
```

and

```
./write/pub/
        |- dir1/
        |- file2
        |- file3
```

I need to create a symlink so that all the content in `./write/pub/` is readable also in `./read/pub/`, but I would like some kind of hybrid directory.

Is it possible to symlink directly the real directory `./read/pub/` to `./write/pub/`, instead of symlinking all its content?
So I could have the possibility to put files in both directory and not have the files in `./read/pub/` present in `./write/pub/`, AND the new files in `./write/pub/` will appear automatically in the `./read/pub/` directory, without recreating the symlinks each time.

PS - I don't think it is possible, but would like to know if you have some kind of solution isntead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want can be achieved by a union mount.

The information in the wikipedia article should get you started: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_mount

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.